# Select Query Does not Work right

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select query which I want to check that if the number of the sensorValue in my database table is not between max and min and the status is equal to 0 then echo a message.

I did something that doesnot work exactly as I want. 
The code is the below

```
//ALERT SYSTEM
     $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT username, typeValue, datetime FROM sensors WHERE sensorValue < min OR sensorValue > max AND status='0'");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
     {
        if($username==$row['username'])
        {
            $alert_message= " <b><font color=red><p align='center'>You Have Health Problem with Your ".$row['typeValue']." at ".$row['datetime']."</font></b>";
            $link_address = "viewsensordata.php?view=".$row['username'];
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $link_address;?>"> <?php echo $alert_message; ?> </a>
            <?php

        }
     }
```

What is wrong with the code and it stills echo the message if the status is 1

Comment: add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`, see if something's failing in there

Comment: Unrelated but you could simplify it to 'WHERE sensorValue NOT BETWEEN min AND max'. Also, I would try to avoid using min and max as column names, as they are also the names of functions in MySQL.

Comment: you also are not doing anything with min and max - consult https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid that you have to put a parenthesis:

```
SELECT username, typeValue, 
datetime FROM sensors 
WHERE (sensorValue < min OR sensorValue > max) 
AND status='0'
```

The "problem" here is that the "and" and "or" have precedence and if I am not wrong, that you have been doing is "sensorValue < min or (sensorvalue > and status ='0')"

Comment: No, he need to put VALUE like 10 and 100 instead of `min` and `max`

Comment: I believe min and max are just placeholders for his example.

Comment: That's a good catch, I'm not sure what the order of precedence is but it might be the solution. Also @Alex if min and max are column names, they will work. It sounds like OP is just getting incorrect results, not an error.

Comment: @taxicala *"I believe min and max are just placeholders for his example."* - pseudo-code always makes things harder for everyone. However, some get lucky sometimes.

Comment: It's not pseudo-code, just placeholders. Did not make it harder for me at least.

Comment: @taxicala More power to you then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need parenthesis:

```
SELECT username, typeValue, datetime FROM sensors WHERE 
(sensorValue < min OR sensorValue > max)
 AND status='0'
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right but I have to accept the other answer because he wrote it first. Upvoted